# How to convert chained jQuery methods to vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know JQuery make our lives much easier, but I'm trying to write some lines in vanilla javascript...so here it goes:

```js
$('.menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Many thanks!

Comment: @phuzi - it's not vanilla, it's 3rd party methods from an arbitrary library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const url = '#2';

document.querySelectorAll('.menu a').forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.getAttribute('href') === url)
     elem.closest('li').classList.add('active')
})

// or shorter:
document.querySelector(`.menu a[href="${url}"]`).parentElement.classList.add('active')
```

```css
.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li><a href='#1'>1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#2'>2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#3'>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

`document.querySelectorAll('.menu a')` - gets all the `a` elements inside `.menu`

#### In Chrome 105+ you can use the :has pseudo selector:

```js
document.querySelector(`.menu li:has(a[href="${url}"])`).classList.add('active')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In my situation the url must be the current href, example var url = window.location.href; Only that it still does not work this way.

Comment: So just change `elem.getAttribute('href')` to `elem.url`

Comment: Nope still no luck. Maybe I have to use filter, just like in JQuery?

Comment: No you don't need to use `filter`. Absolutely not. What is your `url` variable (give an example)? maybe it's a case-issue

Comment: Testing locally it's `./`, when published it gets the path of the page.

Comment: Well... I can't help unless I see the live page and am able to debug what is assigned to the `url` variable and how does the DOM looks like, in terms of the `<a>` `href` attribute. there is a difference calling `.href` property and `getAttribute('href`) method - The `property` returns the full URL of the page + the `href` value.

Comment: Understand and thanks. But why it works perfectly in JQuery and not in pure Javascript?

Comment: Do you see any error or warnings in the console? Just place some `console.log` statements at key-places and try to debug what's happening - find the failure point

Comment: No errors unfortunately.

Comment: Write `console.log(elem.getAttribute('href', elem.href, url) before the `if` statement inside the `forEach` and see what's printed, to see if there's an exact match with your variable

Comment: Worked: had to use `var url = window.location.href;`

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're matching the `href` attribute:

```js
let url = '#l3';

document.querySelector('.menu a[href="' + url + '"]').parentElement.classList.add('active')
```

```css
li.active a { color: green; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#l1">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#l2">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#l3">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#l4">link</a></li>
</ul>
```